# OpenGl - How to repeat a texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is what I have so far :

```
 Rectangle::Rectangle(int x, int y)
  {
    sizeX_ = x * CASE;
    sizeY_ = y * CASE;
    texture_ = gdl::Image::load("./ressources/floor.jpg");
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  }

  void  Rectangle::draw()
{                                                                          
    texture_.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(sizeX_ / CASE, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(sizeX_, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizeY_ / CASE);
    glVertex3f(sizeX_, 0.0f, sizeY_);

    glTexCoord2f(sizeX_ / CASE, sizeY_ / CASE);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, sizeY_);

    glEnd();
  }
```

The constructor takes the size of the map in cases. For example : `(10, 10)`. and the real size will be `(10 * CASE)`, where `CASE = 400`.

But this is not repeating correctly the texture. The texture seems to be reduced (good point) and packed from the up left point to the bottom right point.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: How are `CASE`, `sizeX_` and `sizeY_` defined? Are you doing integer division?

Comment: `CASE` is a macro and `SizeX_` and `sizeY_` are integers.

Comment: Have you checked the projections? If you want pixel-coordinate ratio is 1, you should set your projection to orthogonal and use correct size for viewport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glTexParameter` works on the currently bound texture. It doesn't globally set parameters. This means that you need to bind a texture before calling this function:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```